# jQuery Hover flickers if trigger div and targeted div overlap

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

I have set up a very simple jQuery hover function, but the thing is when you hover over the trigger div, it works but if you move your mouse over the targeted div whilst still on the trigger div (the overlap) it flickers!? Any ideas?

I have this jQuery code:

```
            $("#tag").hover(
              function () {
                $("#homeHover").show();
              }, 
              function () {
                $("#homeHover").hide();
              }
            );
```

With this HTML structure:

```
<div id="homeHover"></div>
<div id="tag">

</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#homeHover {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
background: url("../img/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
top: 145px;
left: 0px;
display: none;
}
#tag {
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger a mouseenter and mouseleave event for the trigger div when you move over the targeted div. This will stop the flickering.

```
$("#homeHover").on({
    mouseenter: function(){
        // Trigger #tag hover to stop flickering
        $('#tag').mouseenter();
    }

    mouseleave: function(){
        // Trigger #tag mouseleave
        $('#tag').mouseleave();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).mouseover(function(e) {
    if (e.target == $("#homeHover").get(0) || e.target == $("#tag").get(0)) {
        $("#homeHover").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#homeHover").hide();
    }

});
```

Comment: oops i dont understand your question

Comment: so now this works. you have to use this because is your mouse is over the tag, the mouse is out of the homeHover, then the homeHover is shown and now the homeHover is over but the tag is out and thats why the blinking occurs. with this global mouseover event capture this detect that any of these is hover at the same time.