# mouseenter, mouseleave and overlay

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

There is no bug, but I would like to know the best tip to deal with this kind of conflict or do it right. How to stop this loop effect.

Here is a basic example :
http://jsfiddle.net/aC5bV/

```
$('a').on({
  mouseenter:function(){
  $tooltip=$('#tooltip');
    $tooltip.animate({
        top:20,
        left:20
    },300);   
  },
  mouseleave:function(){
  $tooltip=$('#tooltip');
    $tooltip.animate({
        top:50,
        left:50
    },300);  
  }
});​
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Stop repeating animation on multiple rollovers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113568/jquery-stop-repeating-animation-on-multiple-rollovers) and [Stopping jQuery animation loop](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9277084/218196) and others...

Comment: yes another stop() question but here I need to finish the first animate to position, a good start but not perfect…

Comment: … just need to add a over test var on complete ! I'm going to do this and post it !

Comment: I'am not a jquery ninja http://jsfiddle.net/aC5bV/12/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found this (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864039/jquery-hover-flickers-if-trigger-div-and-targeted-div-overlap))

```
$(document).mouseover(function(e) {
    if (e.target == $("a").get(0) || e.target == $("#tt").get(0)) {
        $("#tt").animate({top:0,left:0},300);
    }
    else {
        $("#tt").stop().animate({top:200,left:200},300);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aC5bV/13/

If this is improvable, I will accept a better answer !

Answer (score 1):

> How to stop this loop effect?

Use [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/). Please check the manual on the parameters for the best effect.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aC5bV/3/)

```
$('a').on({
  mouseenter:function(){
    var $tooltip=$('#tooltip');
    $tooltip.stop().animate({
        top:20,
        left:20
    },300);   
  },
  mouseleave:function(){
    var $tooltip=$('#tooltip');
    $tooltip.stop().animate({
        top:50,
        left:50
    },300);  
  }
});​
```

Also, you should use `var` when you define a variable, otherwise [you get a global variable](http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/02/global-variables-in-javascript/). And that [dooms the whole world](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/06/01/global-domination) and kills kittens.

Comment: rofl. kills kittens. but you don't have to define a var for this, since you are only using it once :)

Comment: @OptimusCrime That's true. But if you define it, define it correctly.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aC5bV/3/ I know (and forget) stop(), stop(true), stop(true, true), but It's not perfect, ugly cursor blink and on mouseenter the animate doesn't finish… or I forget something ?

Comment: Take a look at this plugin: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html . It only fires when a hover is `intented` not just random pointing with the cursor. Might be something to look into ;)

Comment: @benoît I don't know what you mean by cursor blink. The animation seems nice to me.

Comment: @bažmegakapa not ugly in Chrome, but in firefox, it's different.

Answer (score 1):

use stop() function ...

```
    $('a').on({
  mouseenter:function(){
  $tooltip=$('#tooltip');
    $tooltip.stop().animate({
        top:20,
        left:20
    },300);   
  },
  mouseleave:function(){
  $tooltip=$('#tooltip');
    $tooltip.stop().animate({
        top:50,
        left:50
    },300);  
  }
});
```